# Why isn't this led sequence loop Looping?

Tags: c, embedded

I have started to learn embedded system, and I am asked to write a simple program to light up a 8 leds in a port, first all should be one and then it should light up one after another in a sequence from 7 to 0.

I have written code as following but I am not able to pinpoint why the loop runs only once?

```c
#define BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c"
#define BYTE_TO_BINARY(byte)  \
  (byte & 0x80 ? '1' : '0'), \
  (byte & 0x40 ? '1' : '0'), \
  (byte & 0x20 ? '1' : '0'), \
  (byte & 0x10 ? '1' : '0'), \
  (byte & 0x08 ? '1' : '0'), \
  (byte & 0x04 ? '1' : '0'), \
  (byte & 0x02 ? '1' : '0'), \
  (byte & 0x01 ? '1' : '0')
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0xFF;
    while(x != 0x00)
     {
      x= x>>1;
      printf("%x\n%d",x,i);
      printf("\nBinVal "BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_BINARY(~x));
      x= x<<1;
      i++;
    return 0;
    }
 }
```

I was expecting that x will be continuously right shifted, printing the shifted value. But it's just shifting once `x` goes from `0xFF` to `0x7F` and that's it. Online resources isn't helping me, Will be grateful if someone could guide me.

Comment: Is there a return into the while loop ????

Comment: No actually, Its auto complete by the ide, I didn't realise that it could interfere with output as pointed out by @3ch0

Comment: @FlyingDodo Auto-complete aside, you presumably then enclosed it in the } ?  If you don't understand the language sufficiently to understand what the auto-complete code does, switch it off!

Comment: x will not continuously right shift, because you have a left shift at the end of the loop. The loop will not terminate.

Comment: @Clifford Ah snap, There it is.. Thanks. It's kinda frustrating to debug as beginner. Yes I will switch the auto complete first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   int x = 0xFF;
   while(x != 0x00)
   {
     x= x>>1;
     printf("%x\n%d",x,i);
     printf("\nBinVal "BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_BINARY(~x));
     x= x<<1;
     i++;
     //return 0;   // <- move this out of the loop
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Alex F gave you the correct solution, but did not explain why. Since you would have caught the error, if you knew, I wanted to explain it a bit.

With `return 0` inside your main function, you are telling your program to exit normally. Since the `return` is inside of the loop, you end before it could possibly loop again.

If you are learning to work with embedded systems, I highly recomend reading into the call-stack and how `return`s work (aswell as why `main` should return 0 if everything worked out fine). Otherwise you will run into problems later on.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the last paragraph. Normal embedded systems, that is microcontrollers, don't return from main(). In particular, they don't give a damn about return codes.

Comment: @Ludin can't confirm When I ran it through a gcc compiler it did work.

Comment: Lundin, yes, with simple microcontrollers there will often be a main() that never returns and errors manifest in a different way. However, this main can call functions that do return and status-codes are relevant here. To add tonthaz, working with embedded systems is more than just simple microcontroller-programming. Also, knowing about status-codes can't do any harm.

Answer (score 3):

- `x= x>>1;` gives `0xEF`. `x= x<<1;` gives `0xFE`. It is not equal to zero.
- `return 0;` shouldn't be inside the while loop. Or in your program at all. Bare metal embedded systems don't return from main() and use an impl.defined form such as for example `void main (void)` for that reason.